# Is it good to access spider attributes in scrapy pipeline?

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

In the [scrapy pipeline doc](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html) saids one of the parameter of the function 'process_item' is the spider

process_item(self, item, spider)
Parameters: 
item (Item object or a dict) – the item scraped
spider (Spider object) – the spider which scraped the item

I want to send a list of one type of 'item' to the pipeline, but after many digging through the internet everyone is either yielding or returning the item to the pipeline once at a time.

SamplerSpider.py

```
 class SamplerSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = 'SamplerSpider'
        allowed_domains = ['xxx.com']
        start_urls = (CONSTANTS.URL)
        result = []
```

pipeline.py

```
class SamplerSpiderPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
       // do something here

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        // do something with spider.result
```

Is this a good way to do it? If not then why?

Scraping information from a document will always result in more than one item. Why scrapy pipeline is designed to process the item once at a time?

thanks in advance.

Comment: You *could* do that with some effort if you wanted, but what's wrong with processing the items one at a time (which is kinda the whole purpose of pipelines)?

Comment: Pipelines serve that exact purpose. You can save the full contents of the items and have a different worker to process the saved items.